# Is it a good idea to pause a plot while doing a few one-offs and then going back?

Tags: chapters, flow

This is for my webcomic, and I'm trying my best to keep it about writing, sorry if it's off-topic or something.

Let's say I have 2 chapters of something that tie together and have a continuing plot and stuff. Then I do a quick one-off chapter because it seemed like a good idea. Should I not be doing this and just focusing on the plot chapters? About how many one-off chapters can I get away with before I need to go back to the plot chapters?

Plot chapters and one-off chapters have no interlocking details other than characters.

Webcomic link is in my profile page, I'd put it here but I don't want to seem like I'm advertising too much.

Comment: It depends on what your off chapters are about (flashbacks, backstory, different scene/character, etc.)

Comment: If it's to the benefit of the story in the long run it should be included.   If not, you might want to file it in a nice to have, but not necessary.   Perhaps have a scheduled release where you put out the main story comic on one day of the week, with the non-consiquential story on a different day of the week.  Give a 3-4 day interval between the release so your fans are getting their fix for content but not getting too much of a good thing.